# TaskScheduler and Spring listener

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks, listener

I try to change an entity using Spring TaskScheduler but I get **RollbackException** because Spring auditor can't find currentAuditor. and i don't even know where I can read how to solve my problem. I would be very grateful if someone can help me with the question?

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.geleigeit.LinenAndFlowers.config.auditor.AuditorAwareImpl.getCurrentAuditor(AuditorAwareImpl.java:12) ~[classes/:?]
> at org.springframework.data.auditing.AuditingHandler.lambda$touchAuditor$6(AuditingHandler.java:193) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
> at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[?:?]

```
@Override
@Transactional
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=10000)
public void toInProgress() {
    String currentStatus = "QUEUE";
    String statusToSet = "IN_PROGRESS";
    OrderStatus currentOrderStatus = orderStatusRepository.findByStatus(currentStatus);
    OrderStatus orderStatusToSet = orderStatusRepository.findByStatus(statusToSet);
    try {
        List<Order> orders = repository.findAllByOrderStatus(currentOrderStatus);
        for(Order order : orders) {
            int diff = (int) ((new Date().getTime() - order.getCreatedDate().getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 100));
            if(diff >= 1) {
                order.setOrderStatus(orderStatusToSet);
                repository.save(order);
                logger.info("order status QUEUE was changed to IN_PROGRESS by order.{}", order.hashCode());
            }
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        logger.info("no orders with status QUEUE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem. I just authenticate an user(scheduler) in this method.

```
Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(SecurityUser.fromUser(
            userService.getUser(scheduleId)), Role.ADMIN);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```